# Importing products into Drupal Commerce and handling Tax

Tags: 7, commerce

Im working on an integration module where I'm trying to import products externally and into Drupal Commerce. I revceive the product object externally like this:
    2692604 (Object) stdClass
      id (Integer) 2692604
      revision (Integer) 2
      currencyCode (String, 3 characters ) NOK
      vatType (Integer) 3
      name (String, 14 characters ) Produktkatalog
      priceCurrency (Integer) 235
      priceIncVatCurrency (Integer) 294
      number (String, 4 characters ) 1003
      cost (Integer) 230

I've found a code snippet from the commerce_example module where you can create a product programmatically like this:

```
//commerce_price[und][0][amount]
$price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
  'amount' => $price * 100,
  'currency_code' => commerce_default_currency(),
)));
$form_state['values']['commerce_price'] = $price;

// Notify field widgets to save their field data
field_attach_submit('commerce_product', $new_product, $form, $form_state);

commerce_product_save($new_product);
return $new_product->product_id;
```

I have defined a tax type and a set of tax rates - including a mapping from the code found in the importing object.

I'm thinking the correct way of adding the tax part should be by modifying the code to something like this:

```
//commerce_price[und][0][amount]
$price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
  'amount' => $price * 100,
  'currency_code' => $product_obj->vatType,
  'data' => array('include_tax' => 'MVA_hoy'),
)));
$form_state['values']['commerce_price'] = $price;

// Notify field widgets to save their field data
field_attach_submit('commerce_product', $new_product, $form, $form_state);

commerce_product_save($new_product);
```

Problem is that when I import the products, the tax rate is not set as I would expect it to.
Investigating the newly created product (or an old loaded product) does not give me much clue either...

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution it seems.
It is apparently not enough to add a field under the data array, you also need to add the include_tax field on the same level as amount and currency:

```
//commerce_price[und][0][amount]
$price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
  'amount' => $price * 100,
  'currency_code' => $product_obj->vatType,
  'data' => array('include_tax' => 'MVA_hoy'),
  'include_tax' => 'MVA_hoy',
)));
$form_state['values']['commerce_price'] = $price;
```

Now, when importing products, the tax field is updated.